# C++: Conditional changes in a header file

Tags: c++, if-statement, header, conditional-statements

I am working on a feature, the code changes of which need to be guarded by checking registry keys. In `.cpp` files, I can simply check if the registry key is on or not and subsequently add the code changes. Here's an example:

```
bool isRegistryKeyOn = SomeMethodToCheckRegistryKey();
if(isRegistryKeyOn)
{
    // New code goes here..
}
else
{
    // Older one's here..
}
```

Now, I am facing a problem during changes in the header file. Suppose the header contains the following declarations:

```
class SomeClass
{
    long var;
    ...
};

typedef int A;
```

And as part of the feature, I need this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    long long var;
    ...
};

typedef int A;
typedef long long B;
```

How can I get around this requirement? All solutions, including the out-of-the-box ones are welcome!

Comment: You can't add or change a typedef or a struct/class definition at runtime, C++ isn't a dynamic language.

Comment: @Mat That's what I thought. So, I guess the only solution here is to create a separate header file for the new feature. Is that right?

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve. Try and describe that more precisely, ideally with a minimal example of the feature you desire.

Comment: The problem is more or less completely presented in the question. The new code needs to work in 64-bit mode while the older one works in 32-bit mode. So, what I need is, as mentioned, a `long long` var in the new feature. Also, there are some newer `typedefs` and `macros` in some other headers.

Comment: You can use macros to set the type based on the feature version.

Comment: But, the problem is that the macro needs to be defined when the registry key is on. And that check cannot be added in a header..

Answer (score 0):

Are you hoping to avoid changing the type in multiple places?
You're already using typedefs, why don't you nest them:

```
typedef long long T;

class SomeClass
{
    T var;
    //...
};

typedef int A;
typedef T B;
```

Comment: You misunderstood the problem. I have explained the question in more detail in the comments section of the question.